# Parsing A hiberfil.sys file for a png image

Tags: c

As part of my Computer security course, I am parsing a hiberfil.sys file, looking for PNG files. I am trying this in C. I have the logic ready just that, when it comes to pointers and C I am left totally confused. I am not able to compile the following code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        FILE* fd = NULL;
        FILE* out = NULL;
        unsigned char* buff;
        unsigned char* chunk[1024];
        fd = fopen("hiberfil.sys","r");
        out = fopen("a.png","w+");
        if(NULL == fd)
        {
                printf("\n fopen() Error!!!\n");
                return 1;
        }
        fread(buff,2,1,fd);
        while(1){
        if(*buff==137){
            fread(buff,2,1,fd);
            if(*buff==80){
                fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                if(*buff==78){
                    fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                    if(*buff==71){
                        fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                        if(*buff==13){
                            fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                            if(*buff==10){
                                fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                                if(*buff==26){
                                    fread(buff,2,1,fd);
                                    if(*buff==10){
                                        int * a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
                                        *a=137;
                                        *b=80;
                                        *c=78;
                                        *d=71;
                                        *e=13;
                                        *f=10;
                                        *g=26;
                                        *h=10;
                                        fwrite(a,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(b,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(c,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(d,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(e,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(f,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(g,2,1,out);
                                        fwrite(h,2,1,out);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else continue;
                                }
                                else continue;
                            }
                            else continue;
                        }
                        else continue;
                    }
                    else continue;
                }
                else continue;
            }
            else fread(buff,2,1,fd);
        }
        }
        unsigned char type[4]=0;
        while(type[0]!=73 || type[1]!=69 || type[2]!=78 || type[3]!=68){
        fread(length,sizeof(int),1,fd);
        fread(type,4,1,fd);
        fread(chunk,length+4,1,fd);
        fwrite(length,sizeof(int),1,out);
            fwrite(type,4,1,out);   
        fwrite(chunk,length+8,1,out);
        }
    fclose(fd);
        fclose(out);
        return 0;

    }
```

Thanks alot!
PS: Can some one please help me with the formatting of the code block!

**Edit with errors**

> error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) <<<< Refering to int * pointers
>
> error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘size_t fwrite(const void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’ <<<< Refering to int length i believe.

They seem trivial to me now, but still a small dosage of explanation would help me. As whats up with these pointers?

Comment: Holy Moly!  That's complex.  Maybe look for a way to refactor it with a data structure and a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mistake is:

```
int * a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
*a=137;
*b=80;
*c=78;
```

as only `a` is an `int*`, the rest of the variables are of type `int`. To correct either declare on one line (which is more readable and makes this mistake less likely) or place a `*` before each variable name.

Another mistake (not a compiler error) is the use of `buff`, which is an unitialised pointer when it is used:

```
unsigned char* buff;
/* snip ... */
fread(buff,2,1,fd);
```

A possible fix is:

```
unsigned char buff[2]; /* As 2 bytes appears to be required size. */
```

Comment: Woohoooo!! No bugs!  Thanx! =)

Comment: @digvijay91, no problem. But no compiler errors most defintely does not equal no bugs. I am unsure what compiler you are using but compile with highest warning level and take heed of them (or preferably treat warnings as errors).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hmjd's answer you should consider that an array of a type can be indexed. You don't have to dereference only the first item.

So you can say `buff[i]` (if, say, declared as `unsigned char buff[1024];`), where `i` is a `size_t` or `int` that you increment while you go.

In general it makes more sense to - as your initial idea seems to have been - read chunks of data and then only read the next chunk if you run into the end of the first chunk while you are still detecting whether it's a PNG file or not.

So basically you read through the `hiberfil.sys` until you hit the end of the file in a loop. Within this loop you keep track of a single chunk and perhaps the preceding chunk. Could be done as a ring buffer for example. Then you run the detection code over that chunk (separate function, passing the chunk by reference) and - for example - return the offset into the chunk from your detection function. This way you also know the offset into the `hiberfil.sys` in case you need this and can then extract the PNG file.

Perhaps also read [this](http://home.earthlink.net/~momotuk/pointers.pdf).